# What's the purpose of /etc/pm/config.d and power.d?

Tags: power-management

What is the purpose of `/etc/pm/config.d` and `/etc/pm/power.d`? It's my understand that scripts in `/etc/pm/sleep.d` are run at the time of a power management event such as the computer sleeping, hibernating, resuming and thawing.

What would I use the `config.d` and `power.d` directories for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  /etc/pm/config.d
       The files in this directory are evaluated in C sort order. These
       files can be provided by individual packages outside of pm-utils.
       If a global configuration variable is set, the value set to will be
       appended to the previous value. If any other variable is set, it
       will be ignored. The syntax is simply: VAR_NAME = value. See the
       CONFIGURATION VARIABLES section for valid variables defined by
       pm-utils. External packages can define others, see their respective
       documentation for more information.
```

The hooks for the power state are placed in

**/usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d**

```
distribution / package provided hooks
```

**/etc/pm/power.d**

```
hooks added by the system administrator 

Hooks in /etc/pm/ take precedence over those in /usr/lib/pm-utils/, so the system administrator can override the defaults provided by the distribution.
```

For instance check [this link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PowerManagement/ReducedPower)

Comment: I have a script in `sleep.d` that runs when the lid is closed and opened. I believe lid events are being handled by `systemd` not `pm-suspend` so they should be in `config.d` not `sleep.d`. Perhaps the system treats them the same and it's up to us humans to put them in the right place. The `power.d` description was informative. Thanks kamil.

Comment: @Sean, Ubuntu doesn't use systemd.

Comment: Although that has now changed in version 15, precipitating questions such as http://askubuntu.com/questions/609695/ and http://askubuntu.com/questions/613741/.