# Does Systemd read /etc/pm/.....?

Tags: power-management, systemd

Do systems using `systemd` read and execute scripts in `/etc/pm/sleep.d/` ?

I'm starting to concluded the answer is that `systemd` ignores these scripts. If this is true what is the replacement?

Update: `man systemd-sleep` states scripts can be added to `/lib/systemd/system-sleep/`. The details were insufficient for me but I tried a modification of an [Arch wiki example](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Power_management#Sleep_hooks) and created `/lib/systemd/system-sleep/root-resume.service`.

```
[Unit]
Description=Local system resume actions
After=suspend.target

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/bin/systemctl restart network-manager.service

[Install]
WantedBy=suspend.target
```

My intention is to restart network-manager after resuming because occasionally it isn't working.

This doesn't seem to be doing what I want.

Comment: I found that /etc/pm/sleep.d scripts will still be run if you type `sudo pm-suspend` from cmdline. Just systemd will not use it from its workflow.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Scripts in `/etc/pm/config.d|power.d|sleep.d` are ignored under systemd. Instead a systemd "unit" (service) must be created and enabled.

To restart networking after the system resumes from sleep I created the file `/lib/systemd/system/root-resume.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=Local system resume actions
After=suspend.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/bin/systemctl restart network-manager.service

[Install]
WantedBy=suspend.target
```

Then I activated the service with `sudo systemctl enable root-resume.service`. Enabling the service creates a symbolic link for the file in `/etc/systemd/system/suspend.target.wants/`

Contrary to `man systemd-sleep` service files placed in `/lib/systemd/system-sleep/` are ignored.

Comment: Yes, exactly this was the reason why the "restart network after a suspend" scripts were not working for people running ubuntu with systemd.

Comment: This should be created as `/etc/systemd/system/root-resume.service`.

You should never modify files under /lib as they are managed by the package manager, to avoid cruft and potential breakages on upgrade, not to mention simplifying backups.

Answer (score 3):

No, nor those in `/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d`. But it runs all scripts (not service files) in `/lib/systemd/system-sleep/` with executable bits set.

Here's an example one for calling pm-powersave, modified from `/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/00powersave`.

```
#!/bin/sh

# do not run pm-powersave on ARM during suspend; the 1.5 seconds that it takes
# to run it don't nearly compensate the potentially slightly slower suspend
# operation in low power mode
ARCH=`uname -m`

case $1 in
    pre)  [ "$ARCH" != "${ARCH#arm}" ] || pm-powersave false ;;          
    post) pm-powersave ;;
esac
exit 0
```

$1 is "post" on resume, "pre" otherwise.
$2 in both cases contains either "suspend", "hibernate", or "hybrid-sleep".