# Wireless power management turns back on in 15.04

Tags: networking, wireless, power-management

I have turned off power management for my wireless. I did that in `/etc/pm/power.d/wireless`.

When I try to connect to a network, the power management turns back on. So the connection fails.

I try:

```
sudo iwconfig wlan0 power off
```

The power management is then off, but when I connect it is turned back on.

I added a service as detailed [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/606446/power-management-for-wireless-unable-to-turn-off-in-xubunu-15-04-vivid), it is now initially off. When I try to connect, the power management turns on again.

Output of `lshw -C network`:

```
*-network
   description: Wireless interface
   product: Wireless 7260
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
   logical name: wlan0
   version: 6b
   serial: <redacted>
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=3.19.0-15-generic firmware=25.15.12.0 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abgn
   resources: irq:43 memory:f0400000-f0401fff
*-network DISABLED
   description: Ethernet interface
   physical id: 1
   logical name: virbr0-nic
   serial: <redacted>
   size: 10Mbit/s
   capabilities: ethernet physical
   configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=tun driverversion=1.6 duplex=full link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=10Mbit/s
```

What is happening here? Can I try anything else?

Comment: What is the driver in question? `lshw -C network` Some drivers allow manipulating power management.

Comment: @chili555 it worked before so I don't think that is the case. But the question now has the output of `lshw -C network`.

Comment: I'd guess that power management daemon isn't working with `15.04` or pm-utils isn't working somehow. As a workaround, you can add  `sudo iwconfig wlan0 power off` as `Exec=` line into `.desktop`  in your `~/.config/autostart`, to do it on every login

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This had nothing to do with Ubuntu.

My ISP, which also handles my wifi, blocked it because I did not pay in time.

Answer (score 1):

Hooks in `/etc/pm/` are ignored in Ubuntu 15.04. Instead you have to create systemd services and enable them.

Although first try adding

```
sleep 10
iwconfig wlan1 power off
exit 0
```

to your `/etc/rc.local` file. This should turn of power management at boot and might help with the connection. To permanently disable the power management look [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/606446/power-management-for-wireless-unable-to-turn-off-in-xubunu-15-04-vivid).

More info about hooks in `/etc/pm` not working anymore [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/609695/does-systemd-read-etc-pm). To create systemd services have a look at [ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Power_management#Suspend.2Fresume_service_files).

Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried it, it did not work. Now the power management is initially off.

Comment: For a robust solution see [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/606446/power-management-for-wireless-unable-to-turn-off-in-xubunu-15-04-vivid)