# No network connection after standby or hibernation

Tags: networking, hibernate, standby

I'm in the process of maybe dropping Windows in favour of Ubuntu and I'm going through 'that' learning process.
The biggest niggle I've encountered so far concerns network state on waking from sleep or hibernation.
I'm using an old Sony Vaio Windows laptop and the network adaptor is built in.

Whenever I wake my machine, from either standby or hibernation, it always says I have no network connection even though there is an ethernet cable connected and Wi-Fi is switched on and the only way to restore a connection is to restart the machine, this of course renders both Sleep and Hibernate useless to me.
Anyone got any ideas please? Please keep answers simple enough for a windows user to understand.
Thanks

Comment: See [no wifi after suspend on 15.04 [duplicate]](https://askubuntu.com/questions/638124/no-wifi-after-suspend-on-15-04), [No network connection after suspend\resume](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1100417/no-network-connection-after-suspend-resume) and [Wireless networking not working after resume in Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/452826/wireless-networking-not-working-after-resume-in-ubuntu-14-04). Other than possible solutions these questions will also tell you want kind of information we need and what commands to use to get them from your computer. Edit your question.

Comment: Sorry, not helpful. 
As I said, I'm a newbie and the person who wrote the post you directed me too is obviously more knowledgeable than me.
I know the different prompts in command line language mean different things but don't know what each one means or how to select the one I need to use.
Like I said, please keep it simple enough for a Windows user to understand