# indicator-power status change delay

Tags: 16.04, power-management, indicator

I recently migrated to 64-bit 16.04 LTS from 32-bit 14.04 LTS on my Toshiba L645 laptop. I am facing an issue with power indicator on the unity panel. When I change the power source to battery from AC, the `indicator-power` usually takes about couple of minutes before updating the status. I know that the system/hardware is working fine as the `udevadm monitor -u` instantly outputs on change:

```
UDEV  [3276.620509] change   /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/ACPI0003:00/power_supply/ACAD (power_supply)
UDEV  [3277.010187] change   /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0A:00/power_supply/BAT1 (power_supply) 
UDEV  [3451.378534] change   /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/ACPI0003:00/power_supply/ACAD (power_supply) 
UDEV  [3451.770260] change   /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0A:00/power_supply/BAT1 (power_supply)
```

I think the real problem is the `upower` package that `indicator-power` uses to update its info. When I do `upower --monitor-detail` I can see that it's not updating when the power state is changed. My current version is `upower (0.99.4-2ubuntu0.2)`.

**Update:** This problem is not persistent, i.e. sometimes the `indicator-power` works instantly, sometimes it doesn't.

Here's the `upower daemon` output when unplugged at `11:58:20.495` (notice the `native-path` initially says `BAT1` but quickly changes to `ACAD` at `11:58:20.499` even though the computer is still disconnected. The `native-path` is corrected only at `12:00:21.292`, full two minutes later):

```
[11:58:20.495]  device changed:     /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT1
  native-path:          BAT1
  vendor:               LGC
  power supply:         yes
  updated:              Sat 18 Jun 2016 11:58:20 AM NPT (0 seconds ago)
  has history:          yes
  has statistics:       yes
  battery
    present:             yes
    rechargeable:        yes
    state:               fully-charged
    warning-level:       none
    energy:              4.46 Wh
    energy-empty:        0 Wh
    energy-full:         4.46 Wh
    energy-full-design:  4.4 Wh
    energy-rate:         65.355 W
    voltage:             12.568 V
    percentage:          100%
    capacity:            100%
    technology:          lithium-ion
    icon-name:          'battery-full-charged-symbolic'

[11:58:20.499]  device changed:     /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/line_power_ACAD
  native-path:          ACAD
  power supply:         yes
  updated:              Sat 18 Jun 2016 11:58:20 AM NPT (0 seconds ago)
  has history:          no
  has statistics:       no
  line-power
    warning-level:       none
    online:              no
    icon-name:          'ac-adapter-symbolic'

[11:58:20.499]  device changed:     /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/line_power_ACAD
  native-path:          ACAD
  power supply:         yes
  updated:              Sat 18 Jun 2016 11:58:20 AM NPT (0 seconds ago)
  has history:          no
  has statistics:       no
  line-power
    warning-level:       none
    online:              no
    icon-name:          'ac-adapter-symbolic'

[12:00:21.292]  device changed:     /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT1
  native-path:          BAT1
  vendor:               LGC
  power supply:         yes
  updated:              Sat 18 Jun 2016 12:00:21 PM NPT (0 seconds ago)
  has history:          yes
  has statistics:       yes
  battery
    present:             yes
    rechargeable:        yes
    state:               discharging
    warning-level:       none
    energy:              4.401 Wh
    energy-empty:        0 Wh
    energy-full:         4.46 Wh
    energy-full-design:  4.4 Wh
    energy-rate:         1.754 W
    voltage:             12.105 V
    time to empty:       2.5 hours
    percentage:          98%
    capacity:            100%
    technology:          lithium-ion
    icon-name:          'battery-full-symbolic'
  History (charge):
    1466230521  98.000  discharging
  History (rate):
    1466230521  1.754   discharging

[12:00:21.296]  device changed:     /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT1
  native-path:          BAT1
  vendor:               LGC
  power supply:         yes
  updated:              Sat 18 Jun 2016 12:00:21 PM NPT (0 seconds ago)
  has history:          yes
  has statistics:       yes
  battery
    present:             yes
    rechargeable:        yes
    state:               discharging
    warning-level:       none
    energy:              4.401 Wh
    energy-empty:        0 Wh
    energy-full:         4.46 Wh
    energy-full-design:  4.4 Wh
    energy-rate:         1.754 W
    voltage:             12.105 V
    time to empty:       2.5 hours
    percentage:          98%
    capacity:            100%
    technology:          lithium-ion
    icon-name:          'battery-full-symbolic'
  History (charge):
    1466230521  98.000  discharging
  History (rate):
    1466230521  1.754   discharging

[12:00:21.298]  device changed:     /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT1
  native-path:          BAT1
  vendor:               LGC
  power supply:         yes
  updated:              Sat 18 Jun 2016 12:00:21 PM NPT (0 seconds ago)
  has history:          yes
  has statistics:       yes
  battery
    present:             yes
    rechargeable:        yes
    state:               discharging
    warning-level:       none
    energy:              4.401 Wh
    energy-empty:        0 Wh
    energy-full:         4.46 Wh
    energy-full-design:  4.4 Wh
    energy-rate:         1.754 W
    voltage:             12.105 V
    time to empty:       2.5 hours
    percentage:          98%
    capacity:            100%
    technology:          lithium-ion
    icon-name:          'battery-full-symbolic'
  History (charge):
    1466230521  98.000  discharging
  History (rate):
    1466230521  1.754   discharging

[12:00:21.300]  device changed:     /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT1
  native-path:          BAT1
  vendor:               LGC
  power supply:         yes
  updated:              Sat 18 Jun 2016 12:00:21 PM NPT (0 seconds ago)
  has history:          yes
  has statistics:       yes
  battery
    present:             yes
    rechargeable:        yes
    state:               discharging
    warning-level:       none
    energy:              4.401 Wh
    energy-empty:        0 Wh
    energy-full:         4.46 Wh
    energy-full-design:  4.4 Wh
    energy-rate:         1.754 W
    voltage:             12.105 V
    time to empty:       2.5 hours
    percentage:          98%
    capacity:            100%
    technology:          lithium-ion
    icon-name:          'battery-full-symbolic'
  History (charge):
    1466230521  98.000  discharging
  History (rate):
    1466230521  1.754   discharging

[12:00:21.302]  device changed:     /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT1
  native-path:          BAT1
  vendor:               LGC
  power supply:         yes
  updated:              Sat 18 Jun 2016 12:00:21 PM NPT (0 seconds ago)
  has history:          yes
  has statistics:       yes
  battery
    present:             yes
    rechargeable:        yes
    state:               discharging
    warning-level:       none
    energy:              4.401 Wh
    energy-empty:        0 Wh
    energy-full:         4.46 Wh
    energy-full-design:  4.4 Wh
    energy-rate:         1.754 W
    voltage:             12.105 V
    time to empty:       2.5 hours
    percentage:          98%
    capacity:            100%
    technology:          lithium-ion
    icon-name:          'battery-full-symbolic'
  History (charge):
    1466230521  98.000  discharging
  History (rate):
    1466230521  1.754   discharging

[12:00:21.303]  device changed:     /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT1
  native-path:          BAT1
  vendor:               LGC
  power supply:         yes
  updated:              Sat 18 Jun 2016 12:00:21 PM NPT (0 seconds ago)
  has history:          yes
  has statistics:       yes
  battery
    present:             yes
    rechargeable:        yes
    state:               discharging
    warning-level:       none
    energy:              4.401 Wh
    energy-empty:        0 Wh
    energy-full:         4.46 Wh
    energy-full-design:  4.4 Wh
    energy-rate:         1.754 W
    voltage:             12.105 V
    time to empty:       2.5 hours
    percentage:          98%
    capacity:            100%
    technology:          lithium-ion
    icon-name:          'battery-full-symbolic'
  History (charge):
    1466230521  98.000  discharging
  History (rate):
    1466230521  1.754   discharging

[12:00:21.305]  device changed:     /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT1
  native-path:          BAT1
  vendor:               LGC
  power supply:         yes
  updated:              Sat 18 Jun 2016 12:00:21 PM NPT (0 seconds ago)
  has history:          yes
  has statistics:       yes
  battery
    present:             yes
    rechargeable:        yes
    state:               discharging
    warning-level:       none
    energy:              4.401 Wh
    energy-empty:        0 Wh
    energy-full:         4.46 Wh
    energy-full-design:  4.4 Wh
    energy-rate:         1.754 W
    voltage:             12.105 V
    time to empty:       2.5 hours
    percentage:          98%
    capacity:            100%
    technology:          lithium-ion
    icon-name:          'battery-full-symbolic'
  History (charge):
    1466230521  98.000  discharging
  History (rate):
    1466230521  1.754   discharging

[12:00:21.307]  device changed:     /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT1
  native-path:          BAT1
  vendor:               LGC
  power supply:         yes
  updated:              Sat 18 Jun 2016 12:00:21 PM NPT (0 seconds ago)
  has history:          yes
  has statistics:       yes
  battery
    present:             yes
    rechargeable:        yes
    state:               discharging
    warning-level:       none
    energy:              4.401 Wh
    energy-empty:        0 Wh
    energy-full:         4.46 Wh
    energy-full-design:  4.4 Wh
    energy-rate:         1.754 W
    voltage:             12.105 V
    time to empty:       2.5 hours
    percentage:          98%
    capacity:            100%
    technology:          lithium-ion
    icon-name:          'battery-full-symbolic'
  History (charge):
    1466230521  98.000  discharging
  History (rate):
    1466230521  1.754   discharging

[12:00:21.309]  daemon changed:
  daemon-version:  0.99.4
  on-battery:      yes
  lid-is-closed:   no
  lid-is-present:  yes
  critical-action: HybridSleep
```

However, when back in AC, the change is instant. This delay only occurs when changing the state from AC to Battery!

Comment: Try this: when you have this delay , try running this command `qdbus --literal com.canonical.Unity.Panel.Service.Desktop /com/canonical/Unity/Panel/Service com.canonical.Unity.Panel.Service.Sync > /dev/null ` it should cause all panel indicators to be synced.  I don't have any other suggestion so far

Comment: May be worth to make quick try and reinstall some related packages: `sudo apt-get install --reinstall indicator-power libacl1 libapparmor1 libaudit1 libaudit-common libgudev-1.0-0 libselinux1 libsemanage1 libsemanage-common libsepol1 libsystemd0 libudev1 libupower-glib3 udev upower`

Comment: @Sneetsher : No changes noticed !

Comment: Could you upload to http://paste.ubuntu.com the output of `apt-cache policy indicator-power libacl1 libapparmor1 libaudit1 libaudit-common libgudev-1.0-0 libselinux1 libsemanage1 libsemanage-common libsepol1 libsystemd0 libudev1 libupower-glib3 udev upower`

Comment: Here you go http://paste.ubuntu.com/17643124/

Comment: Try to boot, select recovery then Upstart mode. See if works. Negative results then better to submit a bug report: `ubuntu-bug upower`. I don't have much knowledge about this topic.

Comment: @thethakuri, if you had submitted a report, please add it the question.